# Force member variable to be constructed before base class

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm currently facing following scenario:

```
class foo 
{
public:
    foo ( /* some parameters */ );
};

class bar
{
public:
    bar ( foo & f );
};

// both foo and bar are 3rd party

class base
{
public:
    base ( foo & f ) : m_bar ( f ) {}

private:
    bar m_bar;
};

class derived : public base
{
public:
    derived ( foo & f ) : base ( f ) {}
};

class derived2 : public base
{
public:
    derived2 () : base ( /* well ... */ ) {} 

private:
    foo m_foo;
};
```

As you can see, `foo` and `bar` were designed to  be used like this:

```
foo f ( /* some parameters */ );
bar b ( f );
```

However, I want my wrapper classes to be standalone if needed, and `derived2` needs to be. But, `derived2::m_foo` cannot be just passed to `base` while its uninitialized.

So my question is: Is there a way to force `derived2::m_foo` to construct before `base` ?

The only solution I came up with myself is this:

```
class derived2_foo
{
protected:
    foo m_foo;
};

class derived2 : public base, public derived2_foo
{
public:
    derived2 () : derived2_foo (), base ( m_foo ) {}
};
```

Which should be valid code ( I'm free to be proven wrong ), but I'm not quite sure if I want to like that solution. So I'm here to fish for other ideas.

Comment: Hmm.. you are not supposed to modify a question to incorporate an answer. Future readers of question+answer will be quite confused by the fact that I've seemingly answered something which you already knew.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Sorry, didn't know that. And no idea how to revert edits. But your argument kind of also applies to the first version of your answer, which was just setting `derived2_foo` to `private`, which could've been done in a comment. My question is about other ideas than mine. Anyway, I'll double-edit my question

Comment: Not a big deal. Just keep in mind that SO's greater goal is to build up a huge Q/A knowledge base. Perhaps your question would also be better suited for codereview.stackexchange.com; after all, it seems you already have a working solution but are not sure if it's a good one.

Comment: @ChristianHackl You are right. I had no idea codereview.stackexchange.com even exists

Comment: Except `foobar` hypothetical code gets closed as off-topic on [codereview.se]. If you're going to post on CR, make sure you put up actual code for peer review.

Answer (score 4):

Your basic idea is a good one, but you should use private inheritance so that clients of `derived2` are unware of what's going on inside.

```
class derived2_foo
{
protected:
    foo m_foo;
};

class derived2 : private derived2_foo, public base
{
public:
    derived2 () : derived2_foo(), base ( m_foo ) {}
};
```

I've also changed the order in which your base classes appear in the class declaration. Always make sure that the order in the class declaration matches the one in the initialisation list (just as with member variables). As the [C++ FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/multiple-inheritance#mi-vi-ctor-order) says:

> Note that the order B1 and then B2 [...] is determined by
>   the order that the base classes appear in the declaration of the
>   class, *not* in the order that the initializer appears in the derived
>   class’s initialization list.

Or for an even more official source, the C++ standard at §12.6.2/13.2:

> [...] direct base classes are initialized in declaration order as they
>   appear in the *base-specifier-list* (regardless of the order of the
>   *mem-initializers*).

Another improvement would be putting the `derived2_foo` class into its own "private" namespace:

```
namespace detail
{
    class derived2_foo
    {
    protected:
        foo m_foo;
    };
}

class derived2 : private detail::derived2_foo, public base
{
public:
    derived2 () : derived2_foo(), base ( m_foo ) {}
};
```

Libraries like Boost do that, too. While the `detail` namespace does not technically hide or protect anything, it signals to clients that they are not supposed to depend on its contents.

Comment: (edit: this comment isn't quite right, but I'm leaving it as part of the discussion) Also, it's worth pointing out that Christian changed the order of inheritance for `derived2` to make sure that `derived2_foo` is constructed first before `base`.

Comment: @Cornstalks: Actually, it's only a coding-style issue. The order in which base classes are listed is not significant if you explicitly specify the base-constructor call order via an initialisation list.

Comment: Cool, thanks for teaching me something new. Does that mean that if there are multiple constructors they must all call the super constructors in the same order (so that destruction always happens in reverse order)?

Comment: @Cornstalks: OK, I've just checked again and realised that my comment was nonsense. The order in the class declaration trumps the one in the initialisation list. See https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/multiple-inheritance#mi-vi-ctor-order. Or §12.6.2/13.2 in the standard. I'll add this to the answer.

Comment: Thank you for researching that